# Git mergetool cmd finds no files to be merged, merge cmd does

Tags: git

I am trying to use WinMerge as my mergetool in git. I want to merge branches so i checkout out the branch I want to merge into and type:

git mergetool -myotherbranch-

I get the message: No files need merging.

I then ran get merge -myotherbranch- and it auto resolved a number of files and found 3 conflicts. I didn't merge these files yet. I tried running the mergetool again and it still says there are no files to be merged.

Here is my .gitconfig:

```
[mergetool]
  prompt = false
  keepBackup = false
  keepTemporaries = false
[merge]
  tool = winmerge
[mergetool "winmerge"]
  name = WinMerge
  trustExitCode = true
  cmd = "/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e -dl \"Local\" -dr \"Remote\" $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
```

Why does the merge tool not recognize the differences?

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool:

> [Doc] git-mergetool - Run **merge conflict resolution** tools to resolve merge conflicts

`git mergetool` doesn't do merges, it only helps to resolve conflicts. So first you need to run `git merge`, get your 3 conflicts and the run `git mergetool` to resolve those conflicts.

> [OP] I tried running the mergetool again and it still says there are no files to be merged.

Can you show output from `git status`?